# shell script email notification upon success or failure

Tags: unix, sh

I'm writing a shell script that basically transfers data files through SFTP to a database server and then invokes a pl/sql procedure which loads the data from those files (external tables) into internal database tables.

I've been doing some research on effective exception handling in shell scripts and it appears the `set -e` option can be used to terminate a script with an error whenever any command in the script runs which returns a non-zero exitcode.

So, my plan is to have a script which contains all of the processing that needs to get done (SFTP, moving/deleting files, calling pl/sql procedure, etc...) and to include `set -e` at the top of the script.  I also plan to redirect output to a log file in this script.

Then, I plan to have another script that calls the main processing script and then emails the log that gets produced with either a "Success" or "Failure" indicator in the subject of the email.

Are there any "gotchas" that any of you can foresee in this approach or does this seem reasonable?

Comment: Sounds good, but do you run the risk of ignoring msgs from your FTP job because you get too many of them? I used to have 100+ jobs running a day, and the only messages I got was that my monitorAllJobs script had started, then ended AND of course if there were any errors, I got a separate email about that. Greatly reduced the amt of stuff to look at, but I was also certain that monitors where working. Your needs may differ. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter - good points.  Fortunately for me this job will run once a day.  Now, if we get into the scenario you described, we'll have to come up with a notification scheme like the one you outlined just now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of the feedback on this.

I ended up going with this "wrapper" shell that calls the main processing shell.  A cron is going to launch this daily in my particular case.

Comments are certainly welcome if this can be improved.

```
#!/bin/sh
################################################################################
# Author     : Zack Macomber                                                   #
# Date       : 02/22/2012                                                      #
# Description: Calls main_process.sh and emails results of the process.        #
#              Also appends to master log file                                 #
################################################################################

# Flag any errors that occur during processing
set -e

# Set newly created files to "rw" for everyone
umask 111

#############
# VARIABLES #
#############
EMAIL_RECIPIENTS=my_email@some_domain.com
MAIN_DIR=/scripts/

#############
# FUNCTIONS #
#############
send_email() 
{
   uuencode results.log results.log | \
   mailx -s "DATA_LOAD $1 - consult attached log for details" $EMAIL_RECIPIENTS
}

################
# MAIN PROCESS #
################

cd $MAIN_DIR
sh main_process.sh > results.log && send_email SUCCESS || send_email FAILURE
cat results.log >> pub_data_load.log

exit 0
```

Comment: the code hangs if i remove the uuencode line. Can you help?

Comment: @blackfury I can't even remember what I was using this for...probably best to post a question if you need help...

Comment: Thank you... got the answer after a bit of researching. My mistake actually. Your script works good.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds reasonable.

One thing you may also do make it one command and less scripts:

```
someSFTPscipt &> somelogfile.txt; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Success"; else echo "Failure"; fi
```

1. `someSFTPscipt &> somelogfile.txt;` redirects the output of the script to a logfile
2. `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "Success"; else echo "Failure"; fi` checks whether it succeeded (returned 0) or failed (any other non-zero value). Simply replace the echo with your mail commands.

Comment: The use of `$?` is a bit of an antipattern. Unless you need to know the specific error code for other reasons, `if scp ...; then ...` is more idiomatic, ot even `scp ... && echo Success || echo Failure` if your actions are single commands.

Comment: Also, with `set -e`, failure will cause the script to exit immediately, so you *have* to wrap it in a conditional if you want to do your own error handling!

Comment: @platinummonkey - I've gone the route of calling my "main_process" script from another one using these commands...`cd $MAIN_DIR
sh main_process.sh > results.log && send_email SUCCESS || send_email FAILURE`- send_email is a function.  The process is hanging for some reason.  I can run main_process.sh by itself with no issues though...any thoughts?

Comment: That would indicate the SFTP is hanging. Put a timeout on it, should resolve your problem.